# Should console commands be given without being explicitly asked for?

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

I've seen plenty of the type "Where can I find ?" questions around and a common theme I've noticed is that some users instead of posting a thoughtful answer that either explains how to find said item or where it's location is, they opt to post console commands. To me that just looks lazy and probably not at all what the person asking was looking for.

Cutting back on responses with consoles commands **unless explicitly asked for** would be a good idea. 1 because not everyone on this site uses PC and 2 because most people play games for the challenge not the exploits.

Comment: Plenty? I've seen console commands used to fix bugs, broken quests, and so on, but not things like "Where can I find a Vorpal Blade +1?". I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49499/is-there-a-reliable-continuous-source-for-dragon-locations?rq=1) is an example of what I'm talking about. Second answer on a post with a PS4 tag.

Comment: The issue isn't with console commands being given to fix bugs. That's not where I'm going with this. This is pertaining to lazy answers.

Comment: This is a non-issue, the one example you gave is an exception, rather than the norm.

Comment: @rocky The example you gave didn't include or specify  a console until someone posted a console command as an answer. The onus is on the asker to populate relevant information in their question when they ask it.

Comment: Just on a tangential point: Cheating in a single-player game (using console commands in this case) is perfectly acceptable on Arqade. It's your game and therefore you can choose the experience that you want to have playing it - so while the 'cheat' answer may not be a viable option to you, it may be for the next person who views the question and has every right to be there. Also note: multi-player cheating (wall hacks, aimbotting etc) is not allowed here. Any legal/TOS violations aside, they ruin *other people's* experiences and therefore we chose not to support them here.

Answer (score 5):

> Should console commands be given without being explicitly asked for?

Yes, in fact the opposite is true. Unless an asker explicitly asks for answers which *don't* rely on console commands then a console command is a perfectly valid answer. Sometimes a console command is the best or only answer to a problem, even if it only applies to PC (in which case non-PC players are just out of luck).

The thing to remember is that answers on a question aren't just for the asker, they're for everyone else with the same problem. That means answers don't need to apply to every platform a game appears on, since even if the asker isn't on PC someone else who stumbles across the question might be, and that console command answer helps them.

> To me that just looks lazy and probably not at all what the person asking was looking for.

I disagree. Console commands aren't lazy at all, and some of them can take quite a bit of digging to figure out. If you disagree you're welcome to downvote, but this isn't a valid reason to delete these answers.

> Cutting back on responses with consoles commands unless explicitly asked for would be a good idea [..] because most people play games for the challenge not the exploits.

Everyone plays games for different reasons, and we're not going to ban a specific category of answer just because some users feel they don't fit their play style. Again, if you think these answers miss the point of the question and are therefore not useful then you're free to downvote them. Keep in mind, though, that console commands aren't just posted for folks to get around "the challenge of the game", but to fix game breaking bugs (i.e. Skyrim just bugged out and my follower vanish. What do I do?)

Comment: I will agree with you that console commands are not lazy and that everyone plays for different reasons. I'll be damned if I'm going to let something prevent me from completing a 30+ hour playthrough if I can put in a console command that fixes my issue.